# Splitting a DataFrame based on threshold value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do you go about splitting a dataframe in to dataframes based on a threshold, whilst allowing a few stray values?

For example

```
    speed  time
0       1    20
1       1    21
2       1    22
3       1    23
4       0    24
5       0    25
6       0    26
7       1    27
8       0    28
9       0    29
10      1    30
11      1    31
12      1    32
13      0    33
14      1    34
15      1    35
16      0    36
```

should (with a threshold of 0.5) give the output:

Interval1:

```
    speed  time
0       1    20
1       1    21
2       1    22
3       1    23
```

Interval2:

```
10      1    30
11      1    31
12      1    32
13      0    33
14      1    34
15      1    35
```

Here, a run of three values above or below the threshold is considered significant enough to split the dataframe.

I've looked through the various answers on splitting dataframes, but all of these would split to at the first value under the threshold, not after finding x under the threshold.

The overall aim is to split the following into 4 dataframes:

[image: 1]

The data is speed from a gps, I'm trying to group them into interval workouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `centered rolling mean` with an appropriate threshold.

### Code

```
threshold = 0.5
df["flag"] = df["speed"].rolling(3, center=True).mean().ffill().bfill() >= threshold
df["group"] = df["flag"].diff().cumsum().bfill().astype(int)
```

`.bfill()` and `.ffill()` fills the leading and trailing `NaN`'s respectively.

### Output

The output can be obtained automatically depending on whether the first group is below the threshold or not.

```
ls_out = []
for i in range(df["group"].max() + 1):
    # depends on the flag of the first group
    if (df["flag"][0] and (i % 2 == 0)) or ((not df["flag"][0]) and (i % 2 == 1)): 
        ls_out.append(df[df["group"] == i])
        
for out in ls_out:
    print(out)

   speed  time  flag  group
0      1    20  True      0
1      1    21  True      0
2      1    22  True      0
3      1    23  True      0
    speed  time  flag  group
10      1    30  True      2
11      1    31  True      2
12      1    32  True      2
13      0    33  True      2
14      1    34  True      2
15      1    35  True      2
16      0    36  True      2
```

### Note

It is just a coincidence that `threshold=0.5` worked for this particular sample dataset with `window=3`. In other cases, I'd suggest **choosing an appropriate threshold to best include the values at the group boundary** instead of sticking to a fixed threshold and perform manual look-around.